# What are the steps in building an SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Recently I have been seeing a lot about SDK's in Android and how others have created ones from scratch. There's not a lot of material online on how to go about creating an SDK in Android, so I am asking anyone here who can clarify or give an overview into achieving it. This would be a great help to me, thank you.

P.S. When I say SDK, I mean something like a pre-built kitchen. A foundational piece so to speak.

Comment: You question doesn't have enough specificity as any library with a documented API could be considered an SDK. At best it falls under opinion as to when to call something an SDK.

Comment: I was doing research on SDK and they said that they are a collection of Libraries and Documentations, etc... compared to a Library with only functions.

Comment: I don't understand the question. ¿You want to build an SDK on an IDE?

Comment: While the definition you found is acceptable, note that I have seen/used a "Mobile Ad SDK" which consisted of a single library with documentation. Any company with one or more software libraries directed at programmers may call a piece or the whole "an SDK" at which point it becomes a marketing term not a technical one.

Comment: This is not a serious question.  It's like asking how to write a book, how to build a house, how to cook a dinner.